# Express.js - export/access function within route file

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to export function within route file. Here is my code

app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var others=require('./routes/others')
var app = express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/others', others);
app.use('/users', users);
module.exports = app;
```

others.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.post("/test", function (req, res, next) {
    res.send("success");
});
//Here i want to export function to users js file
var funDef=function(){
console.log("export a function")
}    

moudle.exports=router;
```

How can I export or call funDef in users.js file. I tried the following way but it is not working

users.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var readFun= require("./others.js");

router.post("/testUsers", function (req, res, next) {   
res.send("suceess");
});   
//getting undefined
readFun.funDef();

module.exports=router;
```

Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 3):

Try for the following:

```
function router() {}

        router.prototype.funDef=function(){
          console.log("export a function")
        }    
    moudle.exports.router=router;
```

Another file:

```
 var router = require('router').router;
 var Router = new router();

Router.funDef();
```

EDIT:

```
// module.js
'use strict';
var temp = "this is a test";

module.exports.func = function() {
   return temp;
}

// app.js
'use strict';
 var module = require('./module');
 console.log(module.func());
```

Comment: How funDef() is accessed? I tried 'readFun.funDef()', but i got undefined

Comment: @SubburajI tried your code and still I see the same error (undefined)

Comment: @Subburaj- it's not working either. 
'var router = require('router').router;'. 
logged router and it is showed undefined. When i put 'var router = require('router')' , the variable router holds 
'function router(req, res, next) {
    router.handle(req, res, next)
  }'

Comment: @Subburaj- module.exports.router=router doesn't work for me. did it work for you?

Comment: @Subburaj- No, i have added functions in another empty js and exported using code **module.exports.functionName= function (){--}**, and not added that js file in routes. It'll be great if you can help me out in exporting function within route file.

Comment: @Subburaj- posted my entire code. As your code didn't work I commented **others** route in app.js and removed **module.exports=router** line in others.js and modified function as 
`module.exports.funDef=function(){console.log("export a function")}`

Comment: @Praveen See the edited post.. I edited the post with code block, i think you followed the syntax as lik edited.